# function swapNode does not work in doubly linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, swap, doubly-linked-list

Function `swapNode` swaps 2 nodes in list. The function create `node* temp` to store temporary data then swaps the data of `node* A` and `node* B`. I can not understand why it does not work. Below here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
struct node;
struct list;

typedef struct node node;
typedef struct list list;

struct node
{
    int point;
    char name[30];
    node *next;
    node *prev;
};

struct list
{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
    int count;
};

node *allocateNewNode(int point, char name[30], node *prev, node *next);
list *createList();
bool insertHead(list *listNode, int point, char name[30]);
bool compareName(char a[30], char b[30]);
bool swapNode(list *listNode, char nameA[30], char nameB[30]);

int main()
{
    list *listNode = createList();

    insertHead(listNode, 10, "abc def");
    insertHead(listNode, 9, "qwe rty");
    insertHead(listNode, 8, "ui op");
    insertHead(listNode, 30, "fgh jkl");
    insertHead(listNode, 1234, "akaka");

    swapNode(listNode, "ui op", "abc def");

    node *temp = listNode->head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%-20s%d\n", temp->name, temp->point);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    free(temp);
    printf("\n%d", listNode->count);
    return 0;
}

node *allocateNewNode(int point, char name[30], node *prev, node *next)
{
    node *newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->point = point;
    strcpy(newNode->name, name);
    newNode->next = next;
    newNode->prev = prev;
    return newNode;
}

list *createList()
{
    list *listNode = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
    listNode->count = 0;
    listNode->head = NULL;
    listNode->tail = NULL;
    return listNode;
}

bool insertHead(list *listNode, int point, char name[30])
{
    node *newNode = allocateNewNode(point, name, NULL, listNode->head);
    if (listNode->head)
        listNode->head->prev = newNode;
    listNode->head = newNode;
    if (listNode->tail == NULL)
        listNode->tail = newNode;
    ++listNode->count;
    return true;
}
bool compareName(char a[30], char b[30])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return false;
        if (a[i] == '\0')
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

bool swapNode(list *listNode, char nameA[30], char nameB[30])
{
    node *A = NULL, *B = NULL;
    node *temp = listNode->head;

    for (int i = 0; i < listNode->count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (compareName(temp->name, nameA))
            A = temp;
        else if (compareName(temp->name, nameB))
            B = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        if (A || B)
            break;
    }
    if (!A || !B)
        return false;
    else if (A == B)
        return false;

    *temp = *A;
    *A = *B;
    *B = *temp;

    if (A->prev)
        A->prev->next = A;
    if (A->next)
        A->next->prev = A;
    if (A->prev)
        A->prev->next = A;
    if (A->next)
        A->next->prev = A;
    free(temp);
    return true;
}
```

tks for your help

Comment: Can you say more about _it does not work_?  What are you seeing that is not right?  Explain it please.

Comment: it works like when we comment line `swapNode(listNode, "ui op", "abc def");` in function `main`. it just print out like we only use `insertHead` functions, nothing change

Comment: Lol, well, that doesn't really shine much of a light on the problem, except that `swapNode` is involved. So, what happens in that function that is not right?  Are you using a debugger to trace the steps, or use break points to view variable values?    By the way, there are 4 memory leaks (at least) in your program.

Comment: i have used debugger and I saw the data of `node *A` and `node *B` swapped, but the linked still like before. could you please tell me how does it happen?

Comment: It is not good to edit the original post to _fix_ things as the question is being answered.  Doing this adds confusion to those who are working to answer your questions.  I've rolled the edit you made back to the original content.

Comment: sorry, my bad, I will learn from experience

Answer (score 3):

In `swapNode`, `A` and `B` are initially `NULL`. The loop that searches for the two matching nodes terminates early when either node is found:

```
        if (A || B)
            break;
```

At most one of `A` and `B` will be non-NULL when the loop terminates so at least one of `A` and `B` will be NULL. This causes the function to return `false`:

```
    if (!A || !B)
        return false;
```

To avoid that, you should change the loop to break when both `A` and `B` are non-NULL:

```
        if (A && B)
            break;
```

Also, the loop is only checking `count - 1` elements of the list, so it ignores the final element:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listNode->count - 1; i++)
```

To check all elements, you need to change that to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listNode->count; i++)
```

Alternatively, you could ignore `listNode->count` and check the `temp` pointer instead:

```
    while (temp != NULL)
```

That will work because `temp` is initialized to `listNode->head`, which will be `NULL` for an empty list, and for a non-empty list, the `next` member of the final element on the list is `NULL`, so `temp = temp->next;` will set `temp` to `NULL` when the final element has been checked.

---

There are other problems in `swapNode` related to the actual swapping of the nodes after they have been found.  The original code to do that looks totally wrong:

```
    *temp = *A;
    *A = *B;
    *B = *temp;
```

The `temp` pointer will either be `NULL` or will point to a node after the `A` and `B` nodes.

```
    if (A->prev)
        A->prev->next = A;
    if (A->next)
        A->next->prev = A;
    if (A->prev)
        A->prev->next = A;
    if (A->next)
        A->next->prev = A;
```

The code does not alter `listNode->head` or `listNode->tail` when `A` or `B` is at the head or tail of the list.

```
    free(temp);
```

Why is it freeing `temp` here when all the function is supposed to be doing is swapping nodes?

The code to swap the nodes `A` and `B` needs to be able to deal with neither, either or both nodes being at the end(s) of the list, and with `A` and `B` being adjacent nodes in either order.  Here is a sequence to handle all that:

```
    /* update list head pointer */
    if (listNode->head == A)
        listNode->head = B;
    else if (listNode->head == B)
        listNode->head = A;

    /* update list tail pointer */
    if (listNode->tail == A)
        listNode->tail = B;
    else if (listNode->tail == B)
        listNode->tail = A;

    /* update ->prev->next pointers */
    if (A->prev != NULL && A->prev != B)
        A->prev->next = B;
    if (B->prev != NULL && B->prev != A)
        B->prev->next = A;

    /* update ->next->prev pointers */
    if (A->next != NULL && A->next != B)
        A->next->prev = B;
    if (B->next != NULL && B->next != A)
        B->next->prev = A;

    /* update A->prev and B->prev pointers */
    if (A->prev == B)
    {
        A->prev = B->prev;
        B->prev = A;
    }
    else if (B->prev == A)
    {
        B->prev = A->prev;
        A->prev = B;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = A->prev;
        A->prev = B->prev;
        B->prev = temp;
    }

    /* update A->next and B->next pointers */
    if (A->next == B)
    {
        A->next = B->next;
        B->next = A;
    }
    else if (B->next == A)
    {
        B->next = A->next;
        A->next = B;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = A->next;
        A->next = B->next;
        B->next = temp;
    }
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake, `(A || B)` is my fixed from `(A && B)` when I saw it does not work. So I think that is not the problem

Comment: I think `temp` is not a node of the list so free it is ok?

Comment: @Becker You shouldn't free `temp` because you are not removing elements from the list, you are just changing their order on the list.

Answer (score 1):

Using a debugger you would see that function `swapNode` returns at

```
    if (!A || !B)
        return false;
```

If you would step through the `for` loop you could see that you `break` from the loop when at least one of `A` and `B` is set, i.e. when the first matching node is found.

```
        if (A || B)
            break;
```

Change this to

```
        if (A && B)
            break;
```